# OrderBy with EF on One-To-Many relationship and composite key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, iqueryable, composite-key

Built with EF I have a class Product

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.LanguageProduct = new List<LanguageProduct>();
    }
    [Key, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LanguageProduct> LanguageProduct { get; set; }
}
```

which is linked by a one-to-many relationship to another class that records the name in an unlimited number of languages:

```
public class LanguageProduct
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Languages"), StringLength(6)]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Product name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual LanguagesList Languages { get; set; }
}
```

If you haven't noticed the class LanguageProduct has a composite key based on two foreign keys. Everything works fine until now.
In one of my aspx page I try to populate a dropdownlist order by the product name in one language.

```
public IQueryable GetProductsList()
    {
        var _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        IQueryable query = _db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.LanguageProduct.Where(z => z.Language == "en-US").SelectMany(x => x.ProductName));
        return query;
    }
```

As you might suspect, my issue comes from that query that returns nothing. I've tried anything without succes. Among other things I have added the MultipleActiveResultSets to my connection string which I don't like.
Have you got any indication to solve this?

Comment: it should be `_db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.LanguageProduct.SingleOrDefault(z => z.Language == "en-US").ProductName))`, for safely checking against null, you may use `Where` but instead of `SelectMany`, you need to append `Select(x => x.ProductName).SingleOrDefault()` at the end.

Comment: This method uses the default comparer, and does not order by ProductName.

Comment: You were almost there @KingKing . You answer helped me find the correct one: 
IQueryable query = _db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.LanguageProduct.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Language == "en-US").ProductName);

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` in this case should both be fine (assume you don't have duplicate languages in your database).

Comment: SingleOrDefault return this error: 
The methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: well, nice to know about that, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: As I see I cannot populate the datatextfield like this:
   DataTextField="LanguageProduct.ProductName".
It returns this error: Databinding... does not contain a property with the name 'LanguageProduct.ProductName'
Is there any way to link the text field to a linked table value of the returned IQueryable.